# Подключение к базе

Tags: авторизация, сервер

Здравствуйте, такое дело в MVC 4 internet aplication есть встроеный движок авторизации, это все конечно хорошо, и полезно, НО в web.cofig строка подключения занимает место, а если я хочу отдельно к другой базе подключиться и вносить данные что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Добавляете в файл web.config еще одну строку подключения и подключаетесь к ней. А вообще если вам не нужен стандартный шаблон авторизации, то можно выбрать тип Basic, а не Internet Application